# Is assigning line-height to span element buggy in html?

Tags: html, css

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qhsnX/3/ you can see I have assigned 100px line height to the span element only but this also gives same line height to the text after the span element. The same code:

```css
#titleBox {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #6da662;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
span {
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="titleBox"> <span>I have 100px line height. || </span> I have 0 line height</div>
```

Not only this I can't change the line height of other span element following the first one. http://jsfiddle.net/qhsnX/4/

```css
#titleBox {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #6da662;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#one {
  line-height: 100px;
}
#two {
  line-height: 10px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="titleBox"> <span id="one">I have 100px line height. || </span>  <span id="two">I have 10px line height </span>
</div>
```

Is this a bug in html language?

Comment: This isn't a bug, it's as inline elements works. You are searching for `display: inline-block`, that's inline elements whos behaviour it's like blocks. try `#one { display: inline-block; }` to see the results.

Comment: Settin `display: inline-block` on `#one` makes no difference -- http://jsfiddle.net/qhsnX/6/

Comment: yeah, it makes. See: http://jsfiddle.net/qhsnX/7/ . `#one` have 100px height, and `#one2` have 18px height. Both of them have 100px line-height. Inline elements works as this.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude So does it mean that `line-height` only works for `inline-block` elements?

Comment: No, but the box model it's only affected if it's a block element, so `inline-block` works as inline and as block element simultaneously.

Comment: See how padding works in inline and inline-block elements : https://jsfiddle.net/jexb6f1s/ you have a clue with this fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Line-height is used to represent **space between lines** and is applied to a **block element** not for inline element. You can either change the *span to div* or you can *use "display:inline-block"* property in css

Comment: That's what I said! Upvote to grow you reputation :)

Comment: Line-height applies to all elements, both block and inline.

Comment: But text and span both are `inline` elements and you yourself say _Line-height is used to represent space between lines_. If line-height doesn't work on inline elements then why does it work on text in span element?